# Compare values of one column in a table based on parent and child relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table sample :

```
+----+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | value | CommonField | Parentfield  |  child1   |  child2   |
+----+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | abc   | 123         |              | 123child1 | 123child2 |
|  2 | abc   | 123child1   |          123 |           |           |
|  3 | abc   | 123child2   |          123 |           |           |
|  4 | def   | 456         |              | 456child1 | 456child2 |
|  5 | xyz   | 456child1   |          456 |           |           |
|  6 | def   | 456child2   |          456 |           |           |
+----+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now my problem is that I have to compare 'value' field based on the Parent child relation in the table. I need to find when 'value' field is equal for both child1 and child2 and filter records based on that condition. My table has 1000 rows in the similar way.
I did try self joining the table and created a flag field which tells when 'value' is equal in both child rows.

Here is my Query:

**Query:**

```
    Select p.id,
    p.value,
    p.CommonField,
    p.Parent field,
    p.child1,
    p.child2,
    CASE 
      When p.child1 IS NULL
        THEN p.parentfield
        ELSE c1.parentfield
    END AS Parent1
    CASE 
      When p.child1 IS NULL
        THEN p1.child1
        ELSE p.child1
    END AS child1p
    CASE 
      When p.child2 IS NULL
        THEN p1.child2
        ELSE p.child2
    END AS child2p
 CASE 
      When c1.value = c2.value 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS IS_Childequal
from Table as a
Inner Join Table p ON a.id = p.id
Left Join Table p1 ON p1.commonfield = p.parentfield
Left Join Table c1 ON c1.commonfield = p.child1
Left Join Table c2 ON c2.commonfield = p.child2
```

**Results:**

```
+----+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| ID | value | CommonField | Parent field |  child1   |  child2   | parent1 |  child1p  |  child2p  | IS_childequal |
+----+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | abc   | 123         |              | 123child1 | 123child2 |     123 | 123child1 | 123child2 |             1 |
|  2 | abc   | 123child1   |          123 |           |           |     123 | 123child1 | 123child2 |             1 |
|  3 | abc   | 123child2   |          123 |           |           |     123 | 123child1 | 123child2 |             1 |
|  4 | def   | 456         |              | 456child1 | 456child2 |     456 | 456child1 | 456child2 |             1 |
|  5 | xyz   | 456child1   |          456 |           |           |     456 | 456child1 | 456child2 |             1 |
|  6 | def   | 456child2   |          456 |           |           |     456 | 456child1 | 456child2 |             1 |
+----+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

My new Flag field returns 1 always even if 'value' field is not equal.
What am I doing wrong Here?

Comment: where is the new flag field?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu  :  IS_childequal is FLAG field which returns 1 if equal else 0 .  It must have hidden cos of the scroll.

Comment: if you run your script and display c1.value and c2.value what's the result?

Comment: c1.value and c2.value only get populated for parent row. and not for child rows. But it shows correct value from child rows

Comment: from your query what's the result of c1.value and c2.value? and you think the case did not kick in?

Comment: c1.value = abc   c2.value =abc for the 1st row.
c1.value = xyz   c2.value =def  for the 4th row.
Yes , according to the Case IS_childequal should be 0 for 4th ,5th,6th row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem must be elsewhere because with the sample data you provided your query works fine:

[SQL fiddle with your data and query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3cca8/1)

Result from your query in SQL fiddle (only first row has `IS_Childequal=1` as expected):

```
| id | value | CommonField | Parentfield |    child1 |    child2 | Parent1 |   child1p |   child2p | IS_Childequal |
|----|-------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|---------|-----------|-----------|---------------|
|  1 |   abc |         123 |      (null) | 123child1 | 123child2 |     123 | 123child1 | 123child2 |             1 |
|  2 |   abc |   123child1 |         123 |    (null) |    (null) |     123 | 123child1 | 123child2 |             0 |
|  3 |   abc |   123child2 |         123 |    (null) |    (null) |     123 | 123child1 | 123child2 |             0 |
|  4 |   def |         456 |      (null) | 456child1 | 456child2 |     456 | 456child1 | 456child2 |             0 |
|  5 |   xyz |   456child1 |         456 |    (null) |    (null) |     456 | 456child1 | 456child2 |             0 |
|  6 |   def |   456child2 |         456 |    (null) |    (null) |     456 | 456child1 | 456child2 |             0 |
```

**Edit:** Since you comment that you need `IS_childequal=1` for child rows as well you better use a subquery for getting that value and then join it with the original table using the `ID` the for parents and `ParentField` for childs:

```
select ID, value, CommonField, ParentField, Child1, Child2,
  IS_Childequal, Child1Value, Child2Value
from Table1 as p
left join (select p.ID AS ParentID, p.CommonField as Parent,
    c1.value as Child1Value, c2.value as Child2Value,
    case when c1.value = c2.value then 1 else 0 end as IS_Childequal
  from Table1 as p
  left join Table1 c1 ON c1.CommonField = p.child1
  left join Table1 c2 ON c2.CommonField = p.child2
  where p.ParentField is null)
as parents on p.ID=ParentID or ParentField=Parent
```

Results ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3cca8/8)):

```
| ID | value | CommonField | ParentField |    Child1 |    Child2 | IS_Childequal | Child1Value | Child2Value |
|----|-------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|---------------|-------------|-------------|
|  1 |   abc |         123 |      (null) | 123child1 | 123child2 |             1 |         abc |         abc |
|  2 |   abc |   123child1 |         123 |    (null) |    (null) |             1 |         abc |         abc |
|  3 |   abc |   123child2 |         123 |    (null) |    (null) |             1 |         abc |         abc |
|  4 |   def |         456 |      (null) | 456child1 | 456child2 |             0 |         xyz |         def |
|  5 |   xyz |   456child1 |         456 |    (null) |    (null) |             0 |         xyz |         def |
|  6 |   def |   456child2 |         456 |    (null) |    (null) |             0 |         xyz |         def |
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I need IS_childequal = 1 for child rows as well...i.e that is first 3 rows.

Comment: I updated the answer with a query for getting that results.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what I was looking for.